# How Do I Fix an Error While Reading in a CSV File in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a Windows 10 laptop and I am trying to read in a csv file in Python.
I have tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(‪"C:\Users\dcolu\OneDrive\Documents\tennis.csv")
```

I copied this path above directly from my Files Explorer.
I have also tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("tennis.csv")
```

and both still give me the same error message: No such file or directory

Comment: backslashes are escapes in Python, put an `r` in front of the string if you want to use backslashes, or better yet, only use forward slashes.. that works on windows and linux. `pd.read_csv(‪r"C:\Users\dcolu\OneDrive\Documents\tennis.csv")`

Comment: thank you Todd. I tried that and it says: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier. I also ran it with single quotes and it gave me the same error.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what I gave you if you're running Python3. But "invalid character in identifier" leads me to believe it's an encoding problem or this isn't the line of code that's actually causing the problem.

Comment: It's still providing me with an error. I believe it honestly has something to do with my directory because all that you have provided me makes sense. I believe all these errors are stemming from the file not being found in the first place.

Comment: Try using Windows notepad to create a simple `test.csv` with just say `a,b,c\n1,2,3` and try loading that. If that works ok, perhaps you could share `tennis.csv` with us

Comment: thank you Todd and Martin for the help. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

If the text in the question's snippet was cut-n-pasted from the editor to the browser as-is, then we can see there's hidden unicode data in the line of source code.

```py
>>> r"""df = pd.read_csv(‪"C:\Users\dcolu\OneDrive\Documents\tennis.csv")"""
'df = pd.read_csv(\u202a"C:\\Users\\dcolu\\OneDrive\\Documents\\tennis.csv")'
```

Note the `\u202a` above right after the left parenthesis. The `\u` signifies it as a unicode code point - or character.

Which causes the `SyntaxError`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(‪"C:\Users\dcolu\OneDrive\Documents\tennis.csv")
  File "<input>", line 1
    df = pd.read_csv(‪"C:\Users\dcolu\OneDrive\Documents\tennis.csv")
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

The Python interpreter thinks it's parsing an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(‪r"C:\Users\dcolu\OneDrive\Documents\tennis.csv")

please be sure to put the letter "r" before the file path. I am sure it will work.